# Hangfire execution not affecting database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I set a background task on my application using hangfire. But the problem is on the local machine it works fine and the database changes work as well. On the web server, it also executes but can't make any changes to the database.
Here's the initiation code -

```
public IActionResult CornJobs()
{
    CornExpression? corn = _context.Set<CornExpression>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

    if(corn.PayExpres == null)
    {
        RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("Increase Payment");
    }
    else
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Increase Payment", () => _students.IncreasePayment(), corn.PayExpres);
    }

    if (corn.SMSExpres == null)
    {
        RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("Send Alert");
    }
    else
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Send Alert", () => _students.SendDueAlert(), corn.SMSExpres);
    }

    return View(corn);
}
```

And here is the interface implementation

```
public bool IncreasePayment()
{
    try
    {
        var students = _context.Set<Student>().AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Status == 1 && (x.Batch1 == 1 || x.Batch2 == 1)).ToList();

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            if(GetMonthDifference(student.DateOfReg, DateTime.Now) == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            Due due = new()
            {
                StudentId = student.StudentId,
                Recurring = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM, yyyy"),
                Amount = student.Payment,
                PreviousAmount = student.Due,
                CurrentAmount = student.Due + student.Payment,
                RecurredOn = DateTime.Now
            };

            student.TotalPayment += due.Amount;
            student.Due += due.Amount;

            _context.Update(student);
            _context.Add(due);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What mistake have I made here?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean: "It cant make changes on the database"? Are the tables for HangFire created? Is the Student Table not updating? Are the jobs executed at all?

Comment: `return false;` in catch statement hides everything that goes wrong in `IncreasePayment` method. You are also not using the returned value from this method in the caller. So you will never know what happened in the method. You need to log the exception in the `catch` block so that you can read the logs to know if there is any error and what error if there is any.

Comment: @klekmek Yes the HangFire table was created and the Student Table is not updating.

Comment: @Chetan how can i log exception?

Comment: Use logging framework such as Serilog, log4net etc.